# Inline Oval symbol in LaTeX

Tags: symbols

How can I create an inline oval symbol? I tried to use `\Ellipse` from the bbding package but I get an error saying `Command \Asterisk already defined`. Probably due to the mathabx package that I am also using.

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to look up a symbol or identify a math symbol or character?](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/14/how-to-look-up-a-symbol-or-identify-a-math-symbol-or-character)

Comment: @Johannes_B I have tried the above link and still unsuccessful.

Comment: Ok, I have solved the conflict. Will post the answer after 8 hrs.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `tikz` package can be used for drawing inline as well as displayed figures. The following minimal example shows how to get the inline symbol of an ellipse as you wish:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}

Here is an inline \tikz \draw (0,0) ellipse (10pt and 5pt); symbol for an ellipse.

\end{document}
```

With the the following output:

[image]

You could also put a macro in the preamble to use it multiple times as follows:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes}
\newcommand{\mysymbol}[1][]{
\begin{tikzpicture}[#1]
\node[draw,ellipse,minimum height=5pt,minimum width=10pt](e){};
\end{tikzpicture}
}
\begin{document}

Here is an inline \mysymbol[baseline=(e.base)] symbol for an ellipse.

\end{document}
```

which accepts an optional `[baseline=]` to align with your text as required. More on this can be found [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123895/positioning-tikz-pictures/123900#123900).

The output of the above code is:

[image]

Comment: It would be worth to save the tikz part in a macro.

Answer (score 1):

Here are two versions.  One is a stretched circle.  However, the line-stroke width becomes non-uniform under a stretch, so I offer the second one where two stretched circles are overlaid, in an effort to preserve the appearance of uniform stroke width.

I chose the oval size/aspect with the arguments `{3}[1.5]` to `\scalebox`.  Thee can be changed.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\def\ellipse{\raisebox{-1pt}{\scalebox{3}[1.5]{$\circ$}}}
\def\dellipse{\ooalign{\raise-.25pt\hbox{\ellipse}\cr\ellipse}}
\begin{document}
Here is an \ellipse\ inline ellipse, and one\\
that that has \dellipse\ ``corrected'' line width
\end{document}
```

[image]

Here is a zoom:

[image]