# Align inline tikz nodes text with current line text (in table)

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfplotstable

I have this table, where the first column has inline tikz nodes. I would like the text of the nodes to be vertically aligned with the text of the table.

I found [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123895/positioning-tikz-pictures/123900#123900) about his (among others), the problem is that I can't use `baseline=(v1.base)` to aline v1, because v1 does not know itself before being shown.

(I'm using pgfplotstable, but I don't think that changes anything)

MWE:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}   
\geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[table,pdftex]{xcolor} 
%---------------------------------- tikz ---------------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc,arrows,patterns,external,shapes.callouts,graphs}
\tikzstyle{fancy}=[rectangle,rounded corners=1mm,thick,draw=white,ultra thin,
                   top color=white,bottom color=black!20,%
                   minimum height=.5cm,minimum width=.5cm,inner sep=2pt]


\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Parameters in blue.}
  \label{tab:1024groups1}
  \vspace{1em}

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
    columns/groups/.style={
        string type,
        column name=g.,},
    columns/vmin/.style={
%       string type,
        column name=$n)$,},
    columns/vmax/.style={
        column name=$(n$,},
    columns/density/.style={
        column name=$d$,},
    every head row/.style={
        after row=\midrule},
  every even row/.style={
    before row={\rowcolor{cyan!7}}},
  ]{
        groups,vmin,vmax,density
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0) (v1){1};},2,1,1
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0)(v2){2};},10,100,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0)(v3){3};},10,25,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0)(v4){4};},2,70000,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0) (v1){1};},2,10,1
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0)(v2){2};},100,10,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0)(v3){3};},10,25,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy] at (0,0)(v4){4};},200,7,0
      }

  \vspace{1em}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Anchor them to the base:

```
\documentclass[10pt,a4paper,twoside]{report}

\usepackage{geometry}   
    \geometry{verbose,tmargin=2.5cm,bmargin=2.5cm,lmargin=2.5cm,rmargin=2.5cm}
\usepackage{setspace}
\setstretch{1.5}
\usepackage[table,pdftex]{xcolor} 
%---------------------------------- tikz ---------------------------------------
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning,chains,fit,shapes,calc,arrows,patterns,external,shapes.callouts,graphs}
\tikzstyle{fancy}=[rectangle,rounded corners=1mm,thick,draw=white,ultra thin,
                   top color=white,bottom color=black!20,%
                   minimum height=.5cm,minimum width=.5cm,inner sep=2pt]


\usepackage{pgfplots}          % to print charts
\pgfplotsset{compat=1.9}

\usepackage{pgfplotstable}
\usepackage{booktabs,colortbl}
\usepackage{fixltx2e} 

\begin{document}

\begin{table}
  \centering
  \caption{Parameters in blue.}
  \label{tab:1024groups1}
  \vspace{1em}

  \pgfplotstabletypeset[
  col sep=comma,
    columns/groups/.style={
        string type,
        column name=g.,},
    columns/vmin/.style={
%       string type,
        column name=$n)$,},
    columns/vmax/.style={
        column name=$(n$,},
    columns/density/.style={
        column name=$d$,},
    every head row/.style={
        after row=\midrule},
  every even row/.style={
    before row={\rowcolor{cyan!7}}},
  ]{
        groups,vmin,vmax,density
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0) (v1){1};},2,1,1
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0)(v2){2};},10,100,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0)(v3){3};},10,25,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0)(v4){4};},2,70000,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0) (v1){1};},2,10,1
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0)(v2){2};},100,10,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0)(v3){3};},10,25,0
        \tikz[baseline=0] {\node[fancy,anchor=base] at (0,0)(v4){4};},200,7,0
      }

  \vspace{1em}

\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]