# genealogytree: positioning a tree

Tags: genealogytree

How to change the position of a whole tree on the paper?

I tried to shift my tree 3cm to the right and 10cm down, but it doesn't work:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\pagestyle{empty}

% /gtr/set position=node at position
% (style, no default)
% Adjusts the current graph such that a node of the graph is placed at the given position.
% If the position is given by coordinates, one has to use curly brackets to enclose the position.
% (Handbook ``5.9 tree positioning options'', p.109)

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}

    \genealogytree
    [
        template=signpost,timeflow=down,
        set position=son1 at {3cm,10cm}  % doesn't work :(
    ]{
       parent[id=g1]{
         g[id=son1,male]{son 1}
         c[male]{son 2}
         c[female]{daughter}
         parent{
           g[male]{father}
           p[male]{grandpa 1}
           p[female]{grandma 1}
         }
         parent{
           g[female]{mother}
           p[male]{grandpa 2}
           p[female]{grandma 2}
         }
       }  
     }     

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Of course I should not expect a shifting but setting an absolute position: sorry about!

Comment: This answer should be relevant: https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/123900/121944

Answer (score 1):

Added a `node` and `adjust position`.

```
\documentclass[a4paper,10pt]{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[all]{genealogytree}
\pagestyle{empty}

% /gtr/set position=node at position
% (style, no default)
% Adjusts the current graph such that a node of the graph is placed at the given position.
% If the position is given by coordinates, one has to use curly brackets to enclose the position.
% (Handbook ``5.9 tree positioning options'', p.109)

\begin{document}
  \begin{tikzpicture}
  \node(X)[above=10cm] at (0,0) {}; %added this line
    \genealogytree
    [
        template=signpost,timeflow=down,
        adjust position=son1 right of {0,0} distance 3cm %added this line
    ]{
       parent[id=g1]{
         g[id=son1,male]{son 1}
         c[male]{son 2}
         c[female]{daughter}
         parent{
           g[male]{father}
           p[male]{grandpa 1}
           p[female]{grandma 1}
         }
         parent{
           g[female]{mother}
           p[male]{grandpa 2}
           p[female]{grandma 2}
         }
       }  
     }     

   \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: My tree] - for source have a look to the google-link in my comment below.

Comment: The example works very well - many thanks!

But my more detailled tree - in fact, three trees are joint - still doesn't work. It seems as if the zero-point jumps when I apply "adjust", while the tree keeps its position on the paper.
tex-file and pdf on [https://drive.google.com/drive/folders/1Qes2QmOsUeRmIsEgZhQaEVscJkWCkXao?usp=sharing].
The result is an A2-output. If I choose A3, the tree will be cut at the right side.

Comment: @P.Nessen You should probably post a separate question for this other, bigger, issue.

Comment: solved by work-around: By adding "\usepackage[a3paper,left=-6.9cm,top=2.5cm,bottom=-2.5cm]{geometry}" I got the output I wanted.