# How to position a TikZ picture relative to text?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning

The following question has essentially already [been asked](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123895/positioning-tikz-pictures) on this website (not by me), however none of the answers are satisfactory for my purposes, so I'll ask it again in a way that will hopefully elicit helpful answers.

Consider the following LaTeX document containing two sentences.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]\lipsum[1][2]

\end{document}
```

When this code is compiled with `pdflatex`, the following output is produced.

[image: A simple text document without a TikZ picture]

I would like to position a 1cm wide TikZ square 1cm below and 1cm to the right of the bottom left corner of the capital U letter, as illustrated below. (I've indicated the reference point with a red dot, but this red dot is not supposed to appear in the actual output.)

[image: The desired output]

How can I achieve this?

As a first attempt, I tried the following code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mytikzrec}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[baseline=2cm]%
\draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]\mytikzrec\lipsum[1][2]

\end{document}
```

This produced the following output.

[image: First attempt]

This has two problems. Firstly, I managed to move the square down, but I didn't know how to move the square to the right. Secondly, the normal text flow was disrupted, which is not what I desire. The text should flow as though the picture didn't exist, just like in the case of the first code sample above.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use the `tikzmark` Ti*k*Z library for this:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\begin{document}
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetuer adipiscing elit. \tikzmarknode{U}{U}t purus elit, vestibulum ut, placerat ac, adipiscing vitae, felis.

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]
\draw (U.south west) ++ (1,-1) rectangle ++ (1,-1);
% just for showing the distances
\draw[red,-latex] (U.south west) |- ++ (1,-1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you! Is there a way to achieve a similar output without encapsulating the letter U in a node? By placing an invisible or dummy node between the period and the U?

Comment: @EvanAad, yes, just change `\tikzmarknode{U}{U}t` for `\tikzmarknode{U}{}Ut` and you have it.

Comment: Or just `\tikzmark{U}` before the text. Then use `(pic cs:U)` for the coordinate in the subsequent tikzpicture.

Answer (score 5):

I'd like to suggest a variation on [Juan Castaño's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625994/21685), which uses `\tikzmark` instead of `\tikzmarknode`, which yields a more succinct code.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]\tikzmark{x}\lipsum[1][2]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
   \draw (pic cs:x) ++ (1,-1) rectangle ++(1,-1);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Didn't see this when I left my comment on Juan's answer - yes, this is what I'd use.

Comment: @AndrewStacey, yep, both of you are right, this is simpler.

Answer (score 4):

Although [Juan Castaño answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625994/38080) is more general (learning to use `\tikzmark` is really useful), the simpler answer is --- hide the size of your Ti*k*Z picture with `overlay`, so that it will be considered a 0-size thing by LaTeX:

```latex
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\newcommand{\mytikzrec}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}[overlay]%
\draw (1,-1) rectangle ++(1,-1);%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]\mytikzrec\lipsum[1][2]

\end{document}
```

[image]

(Notice that the units used by Ti*k*Z by default are 1cm in both axes, although you can tweaks that in several ways).

Using `\tikzmark` is much more powerful but often it will require several compilations to get things in place.