# How to position a TikZ picture relative to a \tikzmark?

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, tikzmark

This is a follow-up to [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/625993/21685). I'd like to achieve the same output as described in the question, namely a 1cm wide square that is 1cm below and 1cm to the right of the red dot in the following illustration (the dot should not appear in the output):

[image: Desired output]

Taking a lead from [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/625994/21685), I've attempted to use the `tikzmark` package, but unlike the answer, I tried to use the `\tikzmark` command rather than `\tikzmarknode`. I based my attempt on the first example listed in [the `tikzmark` package documentation](https://ftp.cc.uoc.gr/mirrors/CTAN/graphics/pgf/contrib/tikzmark/tikzmark.pdf) on p. 10, namely on the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}
\[
\tikzmark{a} e^{i \pi/2} = i
\]
This\tikz[remember picture,overlay,baseline=0pt] \draw[->] (0,1em)
to[bend left] ([shift={(-1ex,1ex)}]pic cs:a); is an important
equation.
\end{document}
```

which produces the following output (after compiling twice):
[image: The output of the 1st example given in the TikZ manual]

This output conforms to my expectations and to the drawing shown in the `tikzmark` documentation.

Based on this example, I tried solving the original problem using the following code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]\tikzmark{x}\lipsum[1][2]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
\draw (pic cs:x) ++ (1cm,-1cm) rectangle (1cm,-1cm);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

This produced the following output (after compiling twice):

[image: My attempt]

which is not what I expected for two reasons. Firstly, the shape is a rectangle rather than a square. Secondly, it is positioned to the left of the mark rather than to its right.

Why doesn't my code work as expected? How can it be fixed?

Comment: Try to use `--++` instead of just `++`. And did you compile twice?

Comment: @SebGlav: Yes, I did compile twice. Replacing `++` with `--++` only adds a line from the mark to the rectangle's top right corner.

Comment: See my answer below.

Comment: The rectangle is drawn from the point located (1cm,-1cm) from the (pic cs:x) coordinate to a point which is at the *absolute* (for this Ti*k*Z picture) (1cm, -1cm).  Maybe you want relative coordinate on the second corner?

Comment: @Rmano: How can I specify a relative coordinate for the second corner?

Comment: @EvanAad as shown in the answer by @sebglav, just use `++` on that coordinate too.

Comment: @Rmano: You're right! Thanks! If you write it as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @EvanAad --- it's stated in the last two lines of the existing answer, no need to write another one!

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to draw carefully your square by using `rectangle++` so that your second corner is drawn from the first one.
And here, I used the `calc` library to position exactly the first corner of your square, but other options exist.

[image: tikz relative to tikzmark]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,calc}
\usepackage{lipsum}

\title{}
\author{}
\date{}

\begin{document}

\lipsum[1][1]\tikzmark{x}{}\lipsum[1][2]

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay]%
    \filldraw[red,opacity=0.5] (pic cs:x) circle(2pt);
    \draw ($(pic cs:x) + (1,-1)$) rectangle ++ (1,-1);%
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Without using `calc` library, you can adjust your initial command like this:

```
\draw (pic cs:x) ++ (1,-1) rectangle ++(1,-1);
```

which produces the exact same output.