Combined Tikz picture is not inserted
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a4paper]{geometry}
\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{graphicx}
\usepackage{caption}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{tikz-timing}
\usepackage{float}
\usepackage{overpic}

\batchmode

\begin{document} 

%https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/123895/positioning-tikz-pictures
% "Once you finish a TikZ picture, for TeX it is only a box."

\newcommand{\mypictureB}[1][]{
\begin{figure}
\centering
  \hspace*{-2cm} \begin{overpic}[width=20cm]{example-image-duck}%
\put(16,16){
\begin{tikzpicture}%
  \def\ig{%
    \includegraphics[width=13cm,\transparent{1}]{example-image-duck}}%
 \node [inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\phantom{\ig}};%
 \clip[rounded corners=4mm] ($(mypicture.south west)+(1mm,1mm)$) rectangle ($(mypicture.north east)-(1mm,1mm)$);%
 \node[inner sep=0pt](mypicture) at (0,0) {\ig};%
\end{tikzpicture}%
}
\end{overpic}
\vspace*{-2.5cm} \caption*{test test}
\end{figure}
} 


\mypictureB

\newpage

\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north east)}]
\node[anchor=north east,xshift=-5cm,yshift=-20cm]{\includegraphics[width=5cm]{example-image-duck}};
\end{tikzpicture}

\newpage %This is the picture I would like to insert but it does not appear!
\begin{tikzpicture}[remember picture,overlay,shift={(current page.north east)}]
\node[anchor=north east,xshift=-5cm,yshift=-20cm]{\includegraphics[width=10cm]{\mypictureB}};
\end{tikzpicture}


\end{document} 

Based on the answer of @JLDiaz (Positioning TikZ pictures) "Once you finish a TikZ picture, for TeX it is only a box." I tried the following idea in order to place this "box" (see source code): I combined two pictures in a TikZ environment and defined this combination as a new command ´\mypictureB´. When I apply this new command the (combined) picture is inserted as intended. Now my question: when I try a combination of \begin and \end(Tikzpicture) (see last part of my example code) no picture is inserted( I want to scale and reposition the combined picture as often as I like). Can anyone help me please? Thanks in advance!

Please create a compilable MWE. Remove packages unnecessary to your problem, and provide example-image-aand \myfont.

@Gargantuar: thank you for taking your time to look into the code. I modified my MWE (changed the placceholder picture and removed unnecessary packages as well as \myfont).

I came to this (temporarly) solution using "overpic":
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{overpic}
\usepackage{rotating}
\usepackage{tikz}
\batchmode

\newcommand{\collage}
{\begin{overpic}[
    scale=.5,
  ]{example-image-a}
    \put(5,55){\huge \LaTeX}
    \put(65,50){\includegraphics[scale=.07]{example-image-b}} %relative xy-Position zum ersten Bild
  \end{overpic}}

\begin{document}

\begin{turn}{45}
  \collage
\end{turn}

\newpage

\begin{turn}{22.5}
  \collage
\end{turn}


\tikz[remember picture,overlay]
    \path (current page.north east) ++ (-5,-3) node {\includegraphics{example-image-duck}};

\begin{rotate}{-25} 
\tikz[remember picture,overlay,transform shape,scale=0.5]
    \path (current page.north west) ++ (10,-40) node {\collage};
\end{rotate}

\begin{rotate}{25}    
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,transform shape,scale=0.25]
    \path (current page.south west) ++ (60,25) node {\collage};
\end{rotate}

\begin{rotate}{25}    
    \tikz[remember picture,overlay,transform shape,scale=0.25]
    \path (current page.south west) ++ (50,15) node {\collage};
\end{rotate}
  
\end{document} 

